# cannot readable stack trace in angular sentry

Tags: angular, sentry

I did the following instruction
in angular.json:

```
"sourceMap": {
  "scripts": true,
  "hidden": true
},
```

in main.ts:

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import {AppModule} from './app/app.module';
import {environment} from './environments/environment';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/angular';
import {BrowserTracing} from '@sentry/tracing';

Sentry.init({
  dsn: environment.sentryDsn,
  environment: 'development',
  release : environment.release,
  integrations: [
    new BrowserTracing({
      tracingOrigins: ['localhost', environment.ApiUrl],
      routingInstrumentation: Sentry.routingInstrumentation
    })
  ],
  tracesSampleRate: 1,
});

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

in app.module.ts:

```
...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useValue: Sentry.createErrorHandler({
        showDialog: false,
      }),
    },
    {
      provide: Sentry.TraceService,
      deps: [Router]
    },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => () => {
      },
      deps: [Sentry.TraceService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ]
...
```

And my Makefile is:

```
# Must have `sentry-cli` installed globally
# Following variable must be passed in
#  SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN

SENTRY_ORG=my_org
SENTRY_PROJECT=my_project
PREFIX=dist
SENTRY_CLI=./node_modules/.bin/sentry-cli
VERSION=`$(SENTRY_CLI) releases propose-version`

setup_release: create_release upload_sourcemaps associate_commits

create_release:
    $(SENTRY_CLI) releases -o $(SENTRY_ORG) new -p $(SENTRY_PROJECT) $(VERSION)

associate_commits:
    -$(SENTRY_CLI) releases -o $(SENTRY_ORG) -p $(SENTRY_PROJECT) set-commits --local $(VERSION)

upload_sourcemaps:
    $(SENTRY_CLI) releases -o $(SENTRY_ORG) -p $(SENTRY_PROJECT) files \
        $(VERSION) upload-sourcemaps --url-prefix "~/" --rewrite --validate $(PREFIX)

create_env:
    @echo "version=${VERSION}" > .env
```

"@sentry/angular": "^7.7.0",
"@sentry/tracing": "^7.7.0",
"@angular/cli": "^11.2.11",
"@sentry/cli": "^2.4.1",

The output from Makefile is complete and finish without any error And release is done and all sourceMaps is uploaded on sentry Dashboard, But Still doesn`t recognize where error is trigger
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fat6K.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely a mismatch between either release name (as I see you use `propose-version`, but not sure what `environment.release` points to), or between upload paths.
You'd need to provide `SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=debug` logs and/or more screenshots (artifacts list, event page).